# How to add this type of layout dynamically (android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: this is the format]I have a format which will get repeated only the content of the image/the text inside it will change dynamically.
This format will be added dynamically based on a web result

linear layout
 {
   linear layout
   {
     linear layout
     {image+text}
     linear layout
     {image+text}
     linear layout
     {image+text+image+text+image+text}
  }
}

Comment: Please clarify your question. A mockup will be appreciated. Are repeated layouts swipeable or replace each other or just a single on-screen instance?

Comment: you could make {image + text} as separate layout and add LayoutInflater to inflate view and add data dynamically and add to view using addView method.

Comment: basically , i have to display an result of stuff consisting of images and text.
The result format will remain same (as mentioned above) only the images and the content will change dynamically 
Say:
my output get 3 results,
I need to display these three results in that format

Comment: let me give an answer.

Comment: Not exactly a list view because list view will contain only text( I suppose) 
here i have images along with text.

Comment: A ListView with images is still a ListView. Google ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a layout which holds your format. and declare a layout that's going to hold your dynamic view. using Layout inflater you can add many view as you like.

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View format = inflater.inflate(R.layout.format, null);

    ll.addView(format);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry, I dont understand this part.... 
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(R.layout.parent);
here which is the parent layout  ?? 

View format = inflater.inflate(R.layout.format, null);
Here i specify my layout (my xml file) If i am not wrong

Comment: I have made some changes. LinearLayout ll is where you place your dynamic View and  View format is where you create your dynamic view and append data to it.